# echo html in php with input value as php variable

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP and can't seem to get the following to work. Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to echo a HTML input field and set the value to a variable.

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $one.$two; ?>'>" ;`

What's wrong with this? When I inspect it on the page it does not show the value of the variable.

Comment: `echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='" . $one.$two . "'>" ;`

Comment: The main problem is that you're already executing PHP when you do the first `echo`, so opening another `<?php` within the string you're echoing doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do like this

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='".$one.$two."'>" ;`

Strings and variables are connected with `.`

Comment: Thanks for this I tried everything this was driving me crazy even after your answer I could not get it to work. I did not know that string concatenation required the dots in php. Thanks for your help. It turned out the variables were empty anyway that is why I could not see them.

Comment: What we are doing here is separating html as string and attaching it to the PHP variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$one.$two.'">';
```

I like to echo html using single quotes so input values can use doubles.